# Can't export environment variables on X session start

Tags: bash, debian, environment-variables, awesome, lightdm

My setup is:

- Debian testing (stretch), up to date
- LightDM with autologin enabled
- Awesome window manager
- bash, in ROXTerm or XTerm

I don't seem to be able to set own environment variables and get it sourced at X session startup. Here's what I tried:

- using `~/.bash_profile` worked on my previous OS, but I learned from [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/88108/26514) that it isn't sourced on X startup in Debian and it's derivatives
- I did `mv .bash_profile .profile` as suggested, but it didn't work too because, as I learned later from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/597291/xfce-ligtdm-startup-configuration-files), `~/.profile` isn't sourced when display manager launches X session
- the answer from above question suggests use of `~/.xsessionrc`. This also didn't work because, as I learned from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/598628/etc-x11-xsession-lightdm), it is sourced only by `/etc/X11/Xsession` which LightDM doesn't execute
- Arch Linux wiki [claims](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xprofile) that LightDM sources `~/.xprofile` files, but that didn't work too.

Trying advice from that last site, I made my `~/.xinitrc` like this:

```
export QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE=GTK+
[ -f ~/.xprofile ] && source ~/.xprofile
~/.screenlayout/default.sh
awesome
```

And my `~/.xprofile` like this:

```
[[ -f ~/.bashrc ]] && . ~/.bashrc
source /etc/bash_completion.d/virtualenvwrapper

export GDK_NATIVE_WINDOWS=1
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/env/
```

Sadly, after logging in and starting X session, I see that none of these variables are set:

```
red@localhost:~$ echo $QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE

red@localhost:~$ echo $GDK_NATIVE_WINDOWS

red@localhost:~$ echo $WORKON_HOME
```

How do I set them up properly?

Comment: Note that many graphical login managers do actually source `~/.profile`. GDM, for example. Sadly, you're quite right that not all of them do. That said, the first thing you should try is adding something like `touch /tmp/xprofile` to your `~/.xprofile` and `touch /tmp/xinitrc` to your `~/.xinitrc` etc, so you can figure out which files are actually read.

Comment: Actually, none of these has any effect. I also checked that `awesome` isn't run from `~/.xinitrc` anymore, but configured with `/usr/share/xsessions/awesome.desktop` file that comes with package. This doesn't bring me any closer though. I also tried `~/.pam_environment` which is supposed to work with LightDM, but no luck either.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`~/.xinitrc` is only read when you start a GUI session with `startx` (or otherwise calling `xinit`) after logging in in text mode. So that won't help you.

Whether `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.profile`, `~/.xprofile` and `~/.xsessionrc` are read when logging in with a display manager depends on how the display manager is configured and what session type you select when logging in. As far as I can tell, at least on Debian jessie (I haven't looked if this has changed since then):

- `/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/01_debian.conf` tells Lightdm to use `/etc/X11/Xsession` as the session startup script.
- `/etc/X11/Xsession` (via `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/40x11-common_xsessionrc`) loads `$USERXSESSIONRC` which is `~/.xsessionrc`.

So `~/.xsessionrc` should work, at least on Debian jessie.

On Debian, `~/.pam_environment` should work to set environment variables for any login method.

Alternatively, you can set environment variables and run programs from Awesome via [`~/.config/awesome/rc.lua`](https://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/Autostart#Simple_way) (call `posix.setenv("QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE", "GTK+")` to set an environment variable).

Comment: This is still valid for debian buster / 10.2 . [the part with .xsessionrc]

Comment: This does _not_ work for LD_PRELOAD, LD_LIBRARY_PATH because ssh_agent is started. See `man ssh_agent`. TMPDIR is passed in /etc/X11/Xsession.d/90x11-common_ssh-agent , for the LD_* variables you have to amend 90x11-common_ssh-agent.